# Not creating a file using open() if calling it from inside a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

using Python 2.7.11 and I have a weird problem I havent managed to figure out.

If I have a part of my code that looks like this:

```
with open("test.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("A")
    file.close()
```

It will behave as expected and create a file named test.txt with a 'A' inside.

but if I do the following

```
    def create_file():
        with open("test.txt", "w") as file:
            file.write("A")
            file.close()
create_file()
```

It will not create the file anymore, it doesn't give any kind of error or anything. Checked my os.getwd() and everything, I am confused.

Added a few prints to make sure it was executing the code in the function as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried calling the function???

Comment: @goodvibration edited the OP, already done that and printed some stuff to make sure it was going in

Comment: OK, then try to minimize the problem. Remove the entire program and leave only that small piece of code. Try to execute it outside the function, and then again inside the function. Does the problem persist?

Comment: you don't need `file.close()` if you're using the `with` context

Comment: @goodvibration Comented all code, it works if just have the function declared and calling it, how can I debug this?

Comment: if you've confirmed the function works as expected, it is apparently not being called where you think it is

Comment: Two small comments: 1) Including `open()` in the `with` statement takes care of closing the file for you when you leave the `with` block, so you can remove the `file.close()` calls.
2) Did you maybe overwrite the defined function at another point in your code?

Comment: Regarding debugging: A good Python IDE (there is a ton out there, free and commercial) will allow you to use a graphical debugger to go through your code line by line and also inspect variables (including e.g. the filename, in case that is a variable in your original code (it could just not be avaiöaböe in the function))

Comment: "`Comented all code, it works if just have the function declared and calling it, how can I debug this?`" - with all due respect, this makes the entire question irrelevant (the title by itself is wrong). You should debug your code, investigate the problem, and post relevant findings accordingly **in a new post**.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the function:

```
def create_file():
   with open("test.txt", "w") as file:
      file.write("A")
      file.close()

create_file() #call here
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to actually call the function now.

So:

```
def create_file():
with open("test.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("A")
    file.close()
create_file()
```